# Question to set courseformat core_course_create_courses

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

I want to create a course with reverse week format by using the webservice. What do I have to set in the parameters?

```
courses[0][forcetheme]= string
courses[0][courseformatoptions][0][name]= string
courses[0][courseformatoptions][0][value]= string
courses[0][customfields][0][shortname]= string
courses[0][customfields][0][value]= string
```

Thanks for help

Comment: courses[0][format]=weeksrev is the solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.